# Decomposing a matrix into the tensor product of a permutation and orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, tensor-products

Suppose I have a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{mn \times mn}$.  I want to find

$$\arg \min_{P, Q} \|A - P \otimes Q\|_F$$

where $P$ is an $m \times m$ permutation matrix and $Q$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix.  I cannot find any research on problems like this.  Does anyone have an idea for how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What can you say in the degenerate cases m=1 or n=1?